# Anchor Imageview at view bottom on scrollview layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scrollview layout with several linear layouts inside. The last view of the scrollview is an ImageView which I need to appear always at the bottom of the screen.
The content of the view is dynamic, and sometimes the screen does need to be scrolled and sometimes not.
If the screen needs to be scrolled, the ImageView is shown correctly at the bottom. Take a look at the picture. This is an example of a scrolled screen, the imageView is the green bar.
[image]

And this is an example of a screen that doesn't need to be scrolled, and as you can see, the image view is shown just below the textview.

[image]

And here is my current XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
      >

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen_view11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sector1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/actpercusion" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView TextView TextView TextView"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/lugar_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/boton_web"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/web"
            android:text="Button web" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/boton_web"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/boton_mapa"
          android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/maps"
            android:onClick="openMapa"
                android:text="Button mapa" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
   
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descripcion_texto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen_v"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:src="@drawable/sector3" />
         
    </LinearLayout>

 

</ScrollView>
```

I would need to change my layout file so that the image view always appears at the bottom of the screen, independently if the screen needs to be scrolled or not.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use android:fillViewport

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

See this [blog page](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/comment-page-1/) written by Romain Guy.